# Is it possible to use a Type as a dictionary key in Swift?

Tags: swift, swift3, swift4, swift-protocols, hashable

I’m making a Farm where everything that can be grown conforms to Growable protocol. When you plant a plant, you call this func:

`myFarm.planting<T: Growable>(qty: Int, of: T.Type) -> Farm`

Now I want each instance of Farm to have a dictionary instance var like:

`var crops = [Growable.Type: Int]`

The problem is, even if I make the Growable protocol inherit Hashable, this does not help the Growable *type* become Hashable.

In other words, even if I add an extension to Growable like this:

```
extension Growable {
    static func hashValue {
        // return some hash
    }
}
```

... still the Growable *type* is not Hashable, since the Hashable protocol only concerns *instances of types* but not the types themselves.

Well, normally I would give up and say, “I am stupid, do not attempt this further.”

However this is Swift, so I figure there must be a way to bend the language to my will, whether by making a new StaticHashable protocol and then extending the Dictionary type with a new subscript method accepting this, or by modding Swift’s source code itself and then making a pitch to the Evolution list.

But before I go down either of those paths, I thought it wise to ask you geniuses if there is already a way to do what I want, or whether doing this is incredibly stupid and you will present me with the obviously superior approach that I was unbelievably daft to have somehow missed all along.

Note: my opinion is that Types themselves should be able to statically adhere to protocols whose funcs are not declared as static, since why should the sender of a message care whether the entity that responds is an immortal God or an ephemeral Creature, made in some God’s image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to use a Type as a dictionary key in Swift?

Well its *possible*, here is one way:

```
protocol Growable { ... }

struct S : Growable { ... }
class C : Growable { ... }

extension Dictionary where Key : LosslessStringConvertible
{
   subscript(index: Growable.Type) -> Value?
   {
      get
      {
         return self[String(describing: index) as! Key]
      }
      set(newValue)
      {
         self[String(describing: index) as! Key] = newValue
      }
   }
}

var d : [String:Int] = [:]
d[S.self] = 42
d[C.self] = 24
print(d)
```

prints:

```
["C": 24, "S": 42]
```

If you change the `subscript` definition to:

```
subscript(index: Any.Type) -> Value?
```

you can of course use any type as a key:

```
var d : [String:Int] = [:]
d[S.self] = 42
d[C.self] = 24
d[type(of:d)] = 18
print(d)
```

prints:

```
["C": 24, "S": 42, "Dictionary<String, Int>": 18]
```

I'll leave it up to you to decide whether this is *wise*, but its clearly *possible*.

*[Note: you cannot constrain `Key` to be `String` hence the use of the protocol `LosslessStringConvertible`; there might be a better choice, the Swift standard library is a moving target...]*

HTH

Comment: Yeah this is what I will do. I’m cool with extending Dictionary for now, except I’ll probably try to make a more general StaticHashable protocol and do `return index.hashValue` in the extension. What I really would prefer is for types to be indistinguishable from instances at some level... maybe is Swift 5 heh.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider taking a step back and review your design. You could model your `Growable` plants using *enumerations*, another powerful Swift feature. For instance:

```
protocol Growable {
    /* ... */
}

enum Vegetable: String, Hashable, Growable {
    case carrot, lettuce, potato /* ... */
}

enum Mushroom: String, Hashable, Growable {
    /* ... */
}

struct Farm {
    var crops = [AnyHashable: Int]()
    mutating func plant<T: Growable & Hashable>(qty: Int, of growable: T) {
        crops[growable] = qty
    }
}
```

Using `Hashable` as a concrete type is not supported, as such, we need to use the *type-erased* `AnyHashable` structure instead — protocols with Self *or* associated types requirements can be tricky to get right!

Usage:

```swift
var myFarm = Farm()
myFarm.plant(qty: 10, of: Vegetable.carrot)
myFarm.plant(qty: 20, of: Vegetable.lettuce)
myFarm.plant(qty: 30, of: Vegetable.potato)

print(myFarm.crops)
```

> [AnyHashable(Vegetable.potato): 30, AnyHashable(Vegetable.carrot): 10, AnyHashable(Vegetable.lettuce): 20]

---

**Hashable metatypes**. Regarding your original design, the correct way to express your intent would be:

```swift
extension Growable.Type: Hashable {
    /* make this meta thing hashable! */
}
```

i.e., making the corresponding *metatype* `Hashable` as well, but extending metatypes isn't yet supported by Swift ;)

Comment: I like the enum idea. Another option would be to separate the managing of crops into a `Field` Type. It would separate the logic and potentially allow each `Field` to constrain what `Crops` it can grow.

Comment: Well, the thing is, Growable protocol requires stored properties like `regrowTime` and inherits another protocol that requires `name` and `kind` stored properties as well. Right now they’re static values defined differently in each `struct` that adopts Growable. If I made an enum, since enums cannot have stored properties, how can I structure Growable such that I’ll be guaranteed that each case of an enum will give me a regrow time, a name, and a kind?

Comment: Also, it’s sad that metatypes cannot be extended... very sad... and here I thought Swift was a modern language :S

Comment: @CommaToast An enum can have *computed properties* which might be enough if all 3 properties are fixed (per enum case). Of course, conforming to a second protocol is perfectly possible as well.